# Jquery datapicker CSS not working in IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquerydatetimepicker

I have referred to this datepicker to use in my UI

http://jsfiddle.net/2AaFk/1/

it is working perfectly.

when i copied to work in my UI css is not not working in IE11.

here i have created a plunker link for your reference.

this is what i have done.

https://plnkr.co/edit/D7BmYM1Bb2eZfiZMdk9g?p=preview

> jquery

```
if ( $('#test')[0].type != 'date' ) $('#test').datepicker();
```

this date picker is working in chrome, but css is not working in IE11. can anybody help me.

Comment: The plnkr is broken because you request script over HTTP from an HTTPS URL which wont work, if you fix that then you will not get CSS in Chrome either because you are not including jQueryUI CSS anywhere.

Comment: What css? I see no CSS in your plnkr url...

Comment: @JPHellemons that fiddle also css is not available then how it is working in IE. just open the fiddle

Comment: @Vinoth just opened the jsfiddle url in IE11 and does display the css ;)

Comment: jsfiddle is including jquery-ui.css, perhaps automatically, if you trace the styles thats where they originate from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the CSS. JsFiddle does that for you. For instance, add it from a CDN

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css

source: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jqueryui

[image]

Comment: Hi JP Hellemons, can you tell we i am going to see the css in that fiddle. because i don't  know where to see. in external source there has no css. so that only i am asking

Comment: It's there, see the screenshot in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your advice